# PHP Form for required Fields

Tags: php, sql, forms, require

I have a basic Form that submits data into a database and I want it to require certain fields to be submitted, so far it recongizes that the fields are empty, but it still submits regardless. I can't seem to find a solution..

**Code**

```
<?
// define variables and set to empty values
$asinErr = $qtyErr = $floorErr = $locErr; 
$asin = $quantity = $floor = $location; 

    # this is processed when the form is submitted
    # back on to this page (POST METHOD)
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") 
    {
     if (empty($_POST["asin"]))
         {$asinErr = "ASIN is required";}
     else       
         {$asin = addslashes($_POST["asin"]);}

     if (empty($_POST["quantity"]))
         {$qtyErr = "Quantity is required";}
     else      
         {$quantity = addslashes($_POST["quantity"]);}

     if (empty($_POST["floor"]))
         {$floorErr = "Floor is required";}
     else      
         {$floor = addslashes($_POST["floor"]);}

     if (empty($_POST["location"]))
         {$locErr = "Location is required";}
     else      
     {$location = addslashes($_POST["location"]);}

        # setup SQL statement
    $sql  = " INSERT INTO kiva_amnesty_log ";
    $sql .= " (asin, quantity, floor, location, date) VALUES ";
    $sql .= " ('$asin','$quantity','$floor','$location', now()) ";

        #execute SQL statement
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $cid);

        # check for error
        if (mysql_error()) { print "Database ERROR: " . mysql_error(); }

print "<h3><font color=red>New Amnesty Added - View it <a href=amnesty_log_summary.php>HERE</a></font></h3>";
}

?>
<form name="fa" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">   
    <table>
        <tr><td>ASIN:</td><td><input type="text" name="asin" id="asin"><span class="error">* <?php echo $asinErr;?></span></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Quantity:</td><td><input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity"><span class="error">* <?php echo $qtyErr;?></span></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Floor:</td><td><select name="floor"><option value="1">Floor 1</option><option value="2">Floor 2</option></select><span class="error">* <?php echo $floorErr;?></span></td></tr>
        <tr><td>KIVA Floor:</td><td><input type="radio" value="Yes" name="location">Yes<input type="radio" value="No" name="location">No</select><span class="error">* <?php echo $locErr;?></span></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Amnesty!"></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**Updated:**

```
<?
// define variables and set to empty values 
$asinErr = $qtyErr = $floorErr = $locErr = "";
$asin = $quantity = $floor = $location = "";

    $lb_error = 0;

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")   
{
    if (empty($_POST["asin"])) {
        $asinErr = "ASIN is required";
        $lb_error = 1;
}   else {  
        $asin = addslashes($_POST["asin"]);
}

    if (empty($_POST["quantity"])) {
        $qtyErr = "Quantity is required";
        $lb_error = 1;
}   else {  
        $quantity = addslashes($_POST["quantity"]);
}

    if (empty($_POST["floor"])) {
        $floorErr = "Floor is required";
        $lb_error = 1;
}   else {  
        $floor = addslashes($_POST["floor"]);
}

    if (empty($_POST["location"])) {    
        $locErr = "Location is required";
        $lb_error = 1;
}   else {
        $location = addslashes($_POST["location"]);
}
    if($lb_error) {
    continue;
}
        # setup SQL statement
    $sql  = " INSERT INTO kiva_amnesty_log ";
    $sql .= " (asin, quantity, floor, location, date) VALUES ";
    $sql .= " ('$asin','$quantity','$floor','$location', curdate()) ";

        #execute SQL statement
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $cid);

        # check for error
        if (mysql_error()) { print "Database ERROR: " . mysql_error(); }
```

Comment: You don't check to see if there are any errors before you query the DB. What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1):

You want to check if you error variables are empty. If they are not, then break the script

ie

```
if(!empty($asinErr) || !empty($qtyErr) || !empty($floorErr) || !empty($locErr) ) {
     break;
}
```

Something along these lines.

Check for the errors before you get to the point where you are writing to the database

Comment: A better approach would be to put the errors in the array and then check its size. That way you don't have a huge if statement and the form can grow easily.

Comment: Would this be above my ==POST statement? Never used require before, can't believe I've never used it.

Comment: Aren't these checking to see if they are empty? if (empty($_POST["asin"]))
         {$asinErr = "ASIN is required";}
     else       
         {$asin = addslashes($_POST["asin"]);}

Comment: Yea, but then you arent doing anything with it. If there is a required variable that is empty, you want to break your code so it doesnt continue on and make empty inserts. If you stop the code before then, you will be able to display your errors to the user. I would add it in just above your sql statement

Comment: Okay, awesome! So I can remove my long if empty statements and replace with this single if empty/break statement?

Comment: Well you will need to do checks and assign your error messages to display. So you still need something. In fact what you could do is at the top, have something like $lb_error = 0; Then keep your if/else statements, and if there is an error add $lb_error = 1; Then instead of the original empty check that I suggested, you could do if($lb_error) {break;}

Answer (score 1):

Define at the top

```
$lb_error = 0;
```

Throughout your if/else checks for errors, if there is an error, assign the variable a 1

```
if (empty($_POST["asin"])) {
         $asinErr = "ASIN is required";
         $lb_error = 1;
}     else   {    
         $asin = addslashes($_POST["asin"]);
}
```

Then after you have completed all of these, do a check for errors and break if there are any

```
if($lb_error) {
     break;
}
```

Comment: Updated question, it appears to break; but it goes to a blank screen instead of displaying my is required statement.

Comment: It also blanks when all fields are entered.

Comment: Try continue instead of break

Comment: continue also produces a blank page, whether data is entered or not. Updated my updated code on question.

Comment: Saw this on W3, do I need to.... // define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

Comment: Yep you need to set the variables to ""

Comment: Updated my code on the question it now let's me submit with variables entered, but when no data is entered it goes to blank screen, with my header text there, so getting further at least no more blank white page.